# Expanding div from it's original position to fit the screen

Tags: css

This is what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/xj4hb2kt/4/

```
   .expandable
    {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 1200ms ease-in-out;
        top: 60px;
        left: 100px;
    }

    .expandable-expanded
    {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: scale(100%);
        transform: scale(100%);
        z-index: 5;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
```

Everything works perfectly, except I can't use 'fixed' position for 'expandable' class. Is there any way to do this without having the 'expendable' position set to fixed? thanks!

Comment: Do you want a pure CSS solution or is using `.animate()` an option?

Comment: animate works too. can you check my updated fiddle, maybe it's possible without animate? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this CSS

```
  .expandable-expanded
        {
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-transform: scale(100%);
            transform: scale(100%);
            z-index: 5;
        }
```

and this jquery

```
$('.expandable').click(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    $(this).css('top',$(this).position().top);
    $(this).css('left',$(this).position().left);
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.toggleClass('expandable-expanded');
        self.css('top',0);
        self.css('left',0);
    },100);
});
```

does it work  as your wish?
http://jsfiddle.net/xng4pao6/1/

Comment: Almost. That's the desired effect, but when I click, it 'jumps' before it starts the transition. thanks!